# Skipping indices with a repeater

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt6

How do I skip the indices in a repeater such that I can create the following exact string: `A • D • G • J • M • P • S • V • Z` Is this achievable?

My new code based on suggested answers, I created a function `newLetters(index)` to determine which letters to print and now my output gives the following string: `A •• D •• G •• J •• M •• P •• S •• V •• Z`?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property string letters: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    Rectangle {
        id: control

        anchors.fill: parent
       
    function newLetters(index) {
        if(letters[index] === "A")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "D")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "G")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "J")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "M")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "P")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "S")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "V")
            return true
        if(letters[index] === "Z")
            return true
    }

        Repeater {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: 26
            Text {
                text: control.newLetters(index) ? root.letters[index] : " • "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just set `letters` to exactly that string and render that instead?

Comment: setting Text visible: index !== x is not working?

Comment: I updated my question with new code based on your answer. I'm not sure how to get it exactly like: A • D • G • J • M • P • S • V • Z

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I am trying to use a repeater because I will be adding a MouseArea to each text. I updated my question with new code

Comment: I believe you have to rethink your algorithm. Unfortunately, I doesn't have any experience with QML. What I imagine is an algorithm like the one I sketched in C++: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4d4fef2e75d6c1a).
The trick is to manage the output of `" • "` as a kind of separator instead of the else branch like in your approach. In my C++ sample, I put this into `static` variables. In QML scripting, you might use properties instead (or whatever the scripting language provides to manage some kind of state in a repeater).

Comment: Alternatively, you could extend the else branch of your condition expression with something like `root.letters[index - 1] ? " * " : ""`. (Maybe, introduce yet another function for the 2nd condition.) You have to care about the first iteration, of course. In this case, `index - 1` will be out-of-bound, and this has to be handled as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Loader as delegate.

```
Repeater {
    id: repeater
    model: 26
    Loader {
        sourceComponent: condition(index) ? defaultDelegate : null 
    }
}
```

here `condition` should be a function that returns true for the indices you want to show, and `defaultDelegate` is the delegate you want to show for for those indices.

Another way is to just hide the text element.

```
Repeater {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: 26
    Text {
        visible: condition(index)
        text: root.letters[index]
    }
}
```